# Finding average time from pdf

Tags: probability

The time in hours it takes one construction employee to complete a job has the following pdf:

$ f(t) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  6(t−1)(2−t)  & \mbox{if } 1<t<2 \\
  0 & \mbox{} \text{otherwise}
 \end{array}
\right.
$

a) Find the probability that the average time it takes a random sample of 36 construction employees to complete a job is less than 1 hour and 25 minutes

b) New robot construction employees can complete the job 20% faster. Find the probability that the average time it takes a random sample of 36 robotic construction employees to complete a job is less than 1 hour and 15 minutes

Thanks to everyone for putting me on the right track! And for not just telling me the answer, I feel like I'm learning a lot.

Here's what I've found. Sorry it took me so long to edit, I was looking up the MathJax syntax.

$ E(T) = \int_1^2(t*f(t))\;dt = \frac{3}{2} $

$ E(T^2) = \int_1^2(t^2*f(t))\;dt = \frac{23}{10} $

$ Var(T) = E(T^2)-E(T)^2 = \frac{1}{20}$

Since $ n = 36 \ge 30 $ CLT is valid

Y ~ $N(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{\frac{1}{20}}{36}) = N(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{1}{720}) $

1 hour 25 minutes = 1 + $ \frac{25}{60} = 1.4167 $

$ P(Y < 1.4167) = normalcdf(-\infty, 1.4167, \frac{3}{2}, \sqrt{\frac{1}{720}}) = 0.0127 $

Now, for part b, I'm going to have Q = 0.80(t)

would I find E(U) by

$ E(0.8t) = \int_1^2(0.8t*f(0.8t))\;dt = \int_1^2(0.8t*(18(0.8t)-6(0.8t)^2-12)\;dt $ ?

EDIT:

This seems unlikely. I get

$ E(T) = \int_1^2((0.8t)*f(0.8t))\;dt = 0.96 $

$ E(T^2) = \int_1^2(t^2*f(t))\;dt = 1.403 $

$ Var(T) = E(T^2)-E(T)^2 = 0.4814$

Since $ n = 36 \ge 30 $ CLT is valid

W ~ $N(0.96, \frac{0.4814}{36}) = N(0.96, 0.01337) $

1 hour 15 minutes = 1 + $ \frac{15}{60} = \frac{5}{4} $

$ P(Y < \frac{5}{4}) = normalcdf(-\infty, \frac{5}{4}, 0.96, \sqrt{0.01337}) = 0.9939 $

This seems way too high. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I believe I misunderstood the problem. I thought it was asking what would happen if 36 workers worked together, but upon re-reading it, it's clearly asking for the average time for those workers. I will redo my work, and edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basic Approach.**

Here is a procedure you might follow for (a):

(1) Use the PDF to find $\mu = E(T).$ It might be easier if you multiply the factors of the PDF to get a quadratic expression.

(2) Use  the PDF to find $E(T^2)$ and then $V(T) = E(T^2) - \mu^2.$

(3) Find $E(\bar T)$ and $V(\bar T)$, where $\bar T$ is the sample
mean of 36 workers as above.

(4) By the Central Limit Theorem (CLT), assume that $\bar T$ is
approximately normal with the mean and variance found in (c).
Use the CLT to find the desired probability.

For (b) let $U = aT$, where $a$ is the appropriate constant to
reflect the faster working time for robots. Find $E(U)$ and $V(U)$ based on $E(T)$ and $V(T),$ using standard formulas. Figure out
how to adjust the CLT computation accordingly.

Someone overeager to give too much help too soon may respond by
doing the work for you, but I think that this is a very nice problem and that you will learn something if you
follow the outline above.

Comment: I just did, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Thank you for editing your problem.

Comment: thank you for all your help! I edited in my work for part b, and a question. If you get some time to look at it, I would really appreciate any hints.

Comment: Use $E(cT) = cE(T)$ and $V(cT) = c^2V(T).$ Answers disagree with yours; check your integration. Is it 1 hr 15 min, or 1 hr 25 min? There is no such rule as CLT being OK for n > 30. A symmetrical distribution may approach normal for n = 15 and a badly skewed one (or one with heavy tails) may still noticeably far from normal for n > 100.

Answer (score 0):

**More advanced approach, with some numerical answers.**

If you are familiar with the Beta family of distributions, you can observe that your random variable $T = X + 1,$ where $X \sim Beta(2,2).$ The Wikipedia article 'beta distribution' gives formulas for the mean and variance of $X$ that lead to $E(T) = 3/2$ and
$V(T) = 1/20.$

Because many mathematical statistics packages are programmed to
simulate observations from a beta distribution, it is easy to
simulate the answer to this problem *without* using the CLT. (The principle is exact, but there is some
simulation error.) You can compare this with an answer from the CLT
to see how well the CLT works in this case.

The simulation below in R uses a matrix with 100,000 rows and 36
columns. Each row is one performance of your 36-person experiment.
It indicates that $P(\bar T < 1.4167) \approx 0.012.$

```
 m = 10^5;  n = 36;  t = rbeta(m*n, 2, 2) + 1
 MAT = matrix(t, nrow=m);  t.bar = rowMeans(MAT)
 mean(t.bar < 1 + 25/60) 
 ## 0.01234  # Accurate to 2, probably 3, places
```